# Joining each data frame column on separate table in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, survey

I have survey results that span about 90 columns and over 5K rows. The raw data is keyed in using a code (eg. 1 for "yes", 2 for "no"). Every column has a different number of factor levels: for instance, language spoken at home, income level, etc. How do I replace the original codes with the actual answers on the entire table ?

Here's the structure of the original data:

```
rawsurveydf <- data.frame(Q1_tenant = sample(c(1,2,9), 20, replace=TRUE),
    Q2_income = sample(c(1:9), 20, replace=TRUE), 
    Q3_satisfaction = sample(c(1:4,9), 20, replace=TRUE) )
```

And the translation of each code:

```
Tenantcodes <- data.frame(code=c(1,2,9), Q1_tenant=c("Yes", "No", "Refusal"))
incomecodes <- data.frame(code=c(1:9), Q2_income=as.numeric(c(seq(30000, 110000, by=10^4))))
houssatiscodes <- data.frame(code=c(1:4,9), Q3_satisfaction=c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree", "Refusal"))
```

Comment: I don't understand what the join is.  I believe the issue is that you have factors that have been entered as numeric, is that right? Or are they strings that look like numbers?

Comment: They are the codes used by the firm conducting the survey and they represent an answer that was received to a multiple choice question, including specific codes for cases such as a refusal to answer.

Comment: If you do str(rawsurveydf)  do they show  as factors or numeric?

Comment: For the record, they show up as integers.

Comment: So you want to convert to factor or ordered factor using labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use factors:

```
out <- rawsurveydf
out[] <- Map(function(x,y) factor(x,y$code,y[[2]]),
             rawsurveydf,
             list(Tenantcodes,incomecodes,houssatiscodes))

# out
# Q1_tenant Q2_income   Q3_satisfaction
# 1        Yes     60000 Strongly disagree
# 2         No     90000    Strongly agree
# 3         No     50000             Agree
# 4        Yes     80000           Refusal
# 5    Refusal     70000           Refusal
# 6         No    110000             Agree
# 7        Yes     60000    Strongly agree
# 8         No     40000          Disagree
# 9        Yes    110000 Strongly disagree
# 10       Yes    110000 Strongly disagree
# 11   Refusal     1e+05          Disagree
# 12       Yes     70000    Strongly agree
# 13   Refusal     60000 Strongly disagree
# 14       Yes     40000             Agree
# 15        No     1e+05           Refusal
# 16       Yes     90000           Refusal
# 17        No    110000    Strongly agree
# 18       Yes    110000 Strongly disagree
# 19        No     1e+05           Refusal
# 20        No     90000           Refusal
```

use `as.character(factor(x,y$code,y[[2]]))` instead of `factor(x,y$code,y[[2]])` if you want character columns and not factor columns.

Comment: Thanks this answered my question!  I used `y[[2]][match(x,y$code)]` because some codes translate to a single category (eg. 110,000$ and 120,000$ both belong to ">100,000$") and the factor function wasn't allowing identical labels. Also, I initially had trouble because I was spelling "Map" with a lowercase "m" which is another function in the "purrr" package.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data and code from your (original) example:

```
Tenantcodes$Q1_tenant <- ifelse(Tenantcodes$Q1_tenant=="Yes",2,1)
rawsurveydf           <- merge(rawsurveydf$Q1_tenant, 
                               Tenantcodes, 
                               by="Q1_tenant", 
                               all.x=T)
```

When you need to map values to more than 2 levels you can use other methods like assignment with indexing, `gsub`, etc.

If all of your columns have the same transformations you should just make it into a function and and `apply` or `sapply` the function. If there's a different custom mapping for each column then obviously you'll need to supply that logic for each column.

Comment: Most columns have more than two levels (as in example data), how do I use assignment with indexing or gsub over ~90 columns ?

Comment: @Dealec 1. I reproduced your example data and used it here, unless you changed it afterward 2. Any method can be wrapped in `apply` or `sapply` to avoid looping, so that will scale up to any number of columns without requiring a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you might try is:

```
library(tidyverse)
rawsurveydf <- rawsurveydf %>%
    left_join(y = Tenantcodes, by = c("Q1_tenant" = "code"), suffix = c("", ".answer")) %>%
    left_join(y = incomecodes, by = c("Q2_income" = "code"), suffix = c("", ".answer")) %>%
    left_join(y = houssatiscodes, by = c("Q3_satisfaction" = "code"), suffix = c("", ".answer"))
```

This will give you the desired results while still maintaining the original data.

If you want to set this up to run for all 90 columns, I recommend setting up your "key" in a way that all of the joins can be implemented at one time. This can be achieved by giving the column you call `code` the same name at the column you want to merge it with and naming the answers something different. Maybe like:

```
Tenantcodes<-data.frame(Q1_tenant=c(1,2,9), Q1_tenant_answer=c("Yes", "No", "Refusal"))
incomecodes<-data.frame(Q2_income=c(1:9), Q2_income_answer=as.numeric(c(seq(30000, 110000, by=10^4))))
houssatiscodes<-data.frame(Q3_satisfaction=c(1:4,9), Q3_satisfaction_answer=c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree", "Refusal"))
```

Like this, we can take care of all the joins in one go:

```
result <- list(rawsurveydf, Tenantcodes, incomecodes, houssatiscodes)  %>% reduce(left_join)
```